# Webview doesn't load page on phone screen but on tablet

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I don't understand why if I try to load a page on a WebView on my phone it doesn't load but on tablet it works.
The code of the app:

```
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
            super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
            handler.proceed();
        }


    });

    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            if (newProgress == 100) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            }
        }
    });
```

A restriction on the website?

Comment: Please compare Android versions of the devices

Comment: Both devices with Android 6.0.1